# hadoop can not access the s3

Tags: amazon-s3, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hdfs

I have a question about hadoop access s3 on aws.

```
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>s3n://testhadoophiveserver</value>
</property>

<property>

<name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
<value>I have fill it</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
<value>I have fill it</value>
</property>
```

so .I got a error code when I run start-all.sh.
like this :

```
hadoopmaster: Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: testhadoophiveserver
hadoopmaster:   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.<init>(Client.java:195)

hadoopmaster:   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:850)

adoopmaster:    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:720)

hadoopmaster:   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:220)

hadoopmaster:   at $Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)

hadoopmaster:   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:359)
hadoopmaster:   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:346)
hadoopmaster:   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:383)
hadoopmaster:   at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:314)
```

but ,if I use HDFS ,it's ok.
now ,I can not use S3 filesystem.
who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not run " start-all.sh".
The scripts " start-all.sh" include the code of start HDFS and MapReduce.
It not need to start HDFS if you have configured to use S3 as the underlying storage layer.
The start-dfs.sh is called by start-all.sh, so it will execute the code to start HDFS which you did not configure.